# Delete data in SQL

Tags: sql-server

My problem is about delete data in database. My database has 4 tables :

- Category
- Topic
- Subtopic
- Item
- The `Topic` table has a foreign key (`CategoryID`) referencing the `Category` table
- The `Subtopic` table has a foreign key (`TopicID`) referencing the `Topic` table
- The `Item` table has a foreign key (`SubtopicID`) referencing the `Subtopic` table

I am wondering when I want to delete a category what should I do ? Thank you so much.

Comment: Wondering??? what is not happening as per your expectation?

Comment: is deleting a problem ? knowing `category` is parent table

Comment: What do you expect to see when you delete the category

Comment: My wonder is when I delete a category I should delete each data of sub tables or use "on delete cascade" when I create sub tables.

Comment: As a rule, I have avoided cascading deletes.  Instead I create a stored procedure to handle deleting all of the appropriate data in the correct order for a specific item, e.g. a category.  That way an ad hoc `delete` issued in SSMS won't automagically cascade with horrific consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `on delete cascade` if you delete a category it will delete all topics that have a reference to that category and in turn it all subtopics will be deleted that have a reference to the deleted topics. Same with items.

If you have `on delete restrict` on one of the tables you will get an error saying that you cannot delete the category due to reference constraints.

You can change the behavior of cascade with the proper sql statements or from your dbms UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all the dependent rows in the related tables, you can do cascade delete. Cascade deletes will delete the row from parent table as well as children. If you need all the relationships at multilevel to be deleted automatically, search for "cascade all" syntax for your database flavour.

Answer (score 0):

If I read you correctly (broken, unclear English), you will have to delete the data in `ITEM`, `SUBTOPIC` and `TOPIC` tables that ultimately point back to references to your `CATEGORY` table.  Or, you'll have to drop the references.

Answer (score 0):

`Cascade` will work when you delete something on table `Category`. Any records on child that has reference to table Category will also be deleted.

Here is simple example to define it

```
ALTER TABLE Courses
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId)
REFERENCES Categories(CategoryPK)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```